# Write a script in Linux to run make in every child directory maxdepth of 2

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, csh

I am looking to write a script to go into each child directory (not recursively) and run a make file to create a binary. One way to do this is to change directories and run make for each folder but it's not very elegant and can be error prone if additional folders and files are added.

I have had a little success delving into child dirs with the following:

`find -maxdepth 2 -type f -print -exec make {} . \;`

I get the error for each dir which states the following:

`make: Nothing to be done for reduc211/makefile.`

Anyone got any ideas as to what I can change? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Many thanks and happy coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`make reduc211/makefile` doesn't run the named makefile; it looks for a Makefile using `make`'s lookup rules and tries to make the target `reduc211/makefile`. What you want is something like

```
find -maxdepth 2 -name 'Makefile' -print -execdir make \;
```

This runs the `make` command in every directory where a file named `Makefile` is found.

If you have differently named makefiles, for example each is of the form `Makefile.something`, you could try

```
find -maxdepth 2 -name 'Makefile.*' -print -execdir make -f \{}\ \;
```

to run `make` using the specific Makefiles found by `find`.

Comment: Thanks chpner for a bit of knowledge of what is happening behind the scenes! I tried running the line of code however I get an error related to having the current directory '.' in my path variable. I don;t really have the means to know that I can safely change path as there are many users. Is there an alternative to execdir?

Here is the error: (find: The current directory is included in the PATH environment variable, which is insecure in combination with the -execdir action of find.  Please remove the current directory from your $PATH (that is, remove "." or leading or trailing colons))

Comment: Hm, I wasn't aware of that restriction on `-execdir`. However, it's good advice to remove `.` from your `PATH`, as where an executable is found shouldn't depend on your current working directory. You could also just use `-exec`; it should still work, but it has its own security risk (which is why GNU `find` added `-execdir`).

Comment: Related: [Why using the '-execdir' action of find command is insecure in the PATH?](http://askubuntu.com/q/621132/78223).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
for dir in *; do
    if [ -d "$dir" ]; then
        (cd "$dir" && make)
    fi
end
```